# How do I grow a buffer OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to grow a buffer in OpenGL?

Let's say I want to use instanced rendering. Everytime a spawn a new object in the world I would have to update the buffer with the instanced data.

In this case I have a buffer of 3 floats

```
  std::vector<GLfloat> offsets = {0.0f,0.5f,1.0f};
  auto offset_buffer = buffer::makeBuffer(BufferDraw::STATIC_DRAW, offsets);
```

what if I want to have 4 elements? Do I have to call glBufferData with a bigger size? But what happens with the old data, does it get copied over? Or do I have to delete the buffer entirely and create a new buffer?

Comment: there's an extension that will do it otherwise you will need to allocate the new buffer and copy over the data and fill in the new. Otherwise the old data is lost

Comment: Can I copy the data directly from OpenGL or do I have to send it from my ram to the vram again?

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Which extension is that? The only thing that comes to my mind is [`GL_ARB_sparse_buffer`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sparse_buffer.txt). You could reserve a larger buffer than you need and then commit pages of memory as you fill the buffer up, but the smallest page size that extension requires is 64 KiB and a float is only 4 bytes ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely do not call `glBufferData (...)` with a new size to do this. That is going to orphan the old buffer and give you a new buffer with larger storage (whose contents are unrelated to the previous allocated memory).

The old data will continue to exist for as long as any prior OpenGL commands that need it are still queued up in the pipeline. After those commands finish, the memory is allowed to be reclaimed by OpenGL - you do not have to worry about leaking, but in-place growth does not happen automatically.

GL 3.1 introduced the concept of copy buffers, which will help you do this a lot more efficiently.

#### Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
// Bind the old buffer to `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER`
glBindBuffer (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, old_buffer);

// Allocate data for a new buffer
glGenBuffers (1, &new_buffer);
glBindBuffer (GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, new_buffer);
glBufferData (GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ...);

// Copy `old_buffer_size`-bytes of data from `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER`
//   to `GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER` beginning at 0.
glCopyBufferSubData (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0, 0, old_buffer_size);
```

In real-world situations, you can copy buffer data from any binding location to any other binding location. The new `GL_COPY_..._BUFFER` binding points are convenient, but not necessary, because they don't interfere with any other bindings.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the handle of new_buffer to the handle of old_buffer after I have copied the data? Otherwise I would have to create a new vao.

Comment: @MaikKlein: Well, you could always call `glBufferData (...)` on `old_buffer` _after_ you've copied it to `new_buffer` and then copy the data back. You'd effectively be using "`new_buffer`" as a backup while you resize the original buffer without invalidating the vertex pointers stored in your VAO. Naturally you should avoid small incremental growth if you can by over-allocating buffers that you know are going to grow in size (small amounts of wasted memory would often be preferable to the driver overhead associated with making multiple copies).

Comment: @MaikKlein if you pregen the old_buffer and new_buffer you can just orphan the old buffer and `swap(old_buffer, new_buffer);`

Comment: This code, when translated, gives me a segfault (in python, PyOpenGL). What should I do?