# How to send only new data to opengl without loosing previous data?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working with PointCloud data that I need to render using opengl. I get a new vector of data points every frame. I want that I be able to cache the data previously sent to opengl and only send the newest frame data to it. How can I do so?

I did some searching and found this idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751101/how-do-i-grow-a-buffer-opengl):

```
// Bind the old buffer to `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER`
glBindBuffer (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, old_buffer);

// Allocate data for a new buffer
glGenBuffers (1, &new_buffer);
glBindBuffer (GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, new_buffer);
glBufferData (GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, ...);

// Copy `old_buffer_size`-bytes of data from `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER`
//   to `GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER` beginning at 0.
glCopyBufferSubData (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0, 0, old_buffer_size);
```

But it looks like its finally sending previous and new data in the new buffer instead of caching and sending only the latest data. So I am not sure if its the best way. Please correct me if I am wrong or suggest alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you store some data in your CPU memory, and you append more data to this storage. Then you want to send only the appended data to GPU, not the whole buffer.

Your code example is irrelevant for this task, as `glCopyBufferSubData` copies data from a location in GPU memory to another location in GPU memory again.

You need a combination of `glBufferData` and `glBufferSubData`. `glBufferData` allocates memory in GPU and optinoaly initializes it. `glBufferSubData` writes some data to already allocated GPU buffer. You may treat `glBufferData` as C's `malloc` or C++ `new`, while `glBufferSubData` is like a special version C's memcpy or C++ `std::copy`. More precisely, `glBufferSubData` is `memcpy` from CPU to GPU, and `glCopyBufferSubData` is `memcpy` from GPU to GPU.

How to cook them together? The same way as in C. Call `glBufferData` once at initialization time (when program starts), and call `glBufferSubData` when you need to append data. Be sure to allocate enough space! A buffer allocated by `glBufferData` does not grow, as well as `malloc`ed buffer. Overflowing a buffer with `glBufferSubData` causes undefined behavior and may crash your application.

Try to predict space requirement for your buffer, and call `glBufferData` only if your data does not fit into the buffer.

Remember that calling `glBufferData` with already allocated buffer binding will deallocate existing buffer and create a new one.

`glBufferSubData` will not reallocate your buffer, but will overwrite data which is already there.

Let me illustrate it with C translation:

```
glGenBuffers(..., buf); // float* buf;
glBindBuffer(buf); // Tell opengl that we will use buf pointer, no analog in C.
glBufferData(/*non-null pointer*/); // buf = malloc(/*..*/); memcpy(to_gpu, from_cpu);
glBufferData(/*another non-null pointer*/); // free(buf); buf = malloc(/*..*/); memcpy(to_gpu, from_cpu);
glBufferSubData(...); // memcpy(to_gpu, from_cpu);
```

### Ideomatic approach

What you need is:

```
glGenBuffers(..., buf); // float* buf;
glBindBuffer(buf); // Tell opengl that we will use buf pointer, no analog in C.

// Initialization
glBufferData(/*non-null pointer*/); // buf = malloc(/*..*/); memcpy(to_gpu, from_cpu);

// Hot loop
while (needToRender) {
    if(needToAppend) {
        if (dataDoesNotFit) glBufferData(...); // Reallocate, same buffer name
        else glBufferSubData(...); // memcpy(to_gpu, from_cpu);
    }
}
```

Here we reallocate memory only occasionally, when we need to append something and buffer is too small.

### Other approaches

I advised to reallocate with `glBufferData` as you already have all data in a single buffer on CPU. If not (i.e. you have a chunk of data on GPU and another chunk on CPU, but not together), you could use `glCopyBufferSubData` for reallocating:

```
glBufferData(/*alloc new_gpu_buffer*/);
glCopyBufferSubData(/*from old_gpu_buffer to new_gpu_buffer*/);
glDeleteBuffers(/*old_gpu_buffer*/);
glBufferSubData(/*from_cpu_buffer to new_cpu_buffer*/)p; // Add some new data from CPU.
```

Another approach for updating GPU data is [mapping](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml) it to CPU, so you just access GPU memory by pointer. It's likely to be slow (blocks the buffer, stalls the pipeline), and is useful only in special cases. Use it if you know what you do.

Comment: @Sergey I didn't get how to calculate `dataDoesNotFit`.

Comment: @leehuang It's up to you to decide. For example, you know that you allocated N bytes buffer with initial `glBufferData`, and initialized it with `std::vector<float> data`, where `data.size() < N`. Now you want to append `std::vector<float> moreData`. So calculate `dataDoesNotFit` as `const bool dataDoesNotFit = data.size() + moreData.size() > N;`

Answer (score 2):

Since OpenGL is an API focused on drawing things (ignoring compute shaders for the moment) and when drawing a scene you normally start from an empty canvas, you'll have to retain the complete backlog of point cloud data throughout for the whole span of time, you want to be able to redraw.

Assuming that for large amounts of point cloud data, redrawing the whole set might take some time, some form of cachine might seem reasonable. But let's do some back of the envelope calculateions first:

Typical GPUs these days are perfectly capable of performing full vertex setup at a rate well over 10^9 vertices / second (already 20 years ago GPUs were able to do something on the order of 20·10^6 vertices / second). Your typical computer display has less than 10·10^6 pixels. So because of the pigeonhole principle, if you were to draw more than 10·10^6 points you're either producing serious overdraw or fill up most of the pixels; in practice it's going to be somewhere inbetween.

But as we've already seen, GPUs are more than capable of drawing that many points at interactive framerates. And drawing any more of them will likely fill up your screen or occlude data.

Some form of data retirement is required, if you want the whole thing to remain readable. And for any size of pointcloud that is readable your GPU will be able to redraw the whole thing just fine.

Considering the need for data retirement, I suggest you allocate a large buffer, that is able to hold a whole set of points over their lifetime, before eviction, and use it as a circular round robin buffer: Have an offset where you write over new data as it arrives (using `glBufferSubData`), at the edges you may have to split this in two calls, pass the latest writing index as a uniform, to fade out points by their age, and then just submit a single `glDrawElements` call to draw the whole content of that buffer in one go.

Comment: I haven't really got how to explicitly mention the size of buffer while creating a vbo. Can you please provide some code to allocate a certain sized vbo?

Comment: @leehuang: To initialize a buffer object you either use `glBufferData` (resizable buffer) or `glBufferStorage` (fixed size buffer – I recommend that). Either function has a `size` parameter, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: But isn't the size variable set according to how much data I am buffering at the moment? Or can I send less data but send the size to be larger to allocate extra?

Comment: @leehuang: OpenGL buffer objects just have to be large enough to hold whatever is going into them. They may be much larger. *There is no need to size them to exactly match their contents.* As a matter of fact it's highly discouraged to do so. The best practice is to use buffer objects as memory pools from which free space is taken as needed, and put back when no longer in use.